# Contact address inherits account address

Tags: trigger, workflow, formula

Evening Guys

When inserting new contacts via the Api , I am experiencing that the newly created contacts are not being populated with the address on the account.

I some how need to build a workflow or trigger which says

If newly created contact are inserted without an contact address then inherit the account address.

However if the account address changes and the contacts details are populated with an address then the workflow shouldn't fire.

Looking forward to your help

Answer (score 0):

A workflow rule should suffice:

```
Rule Criteria:
    (Contact: Mailing Street equals null) and 
    (Contact: Mailing City equals null) and 
    (Contact: Mailing State/Province equals null) and 
    (Contact: Mailing Zip/Postal Code equals null) and 
    (Contact: Mailing Country equals null)
Evaluation Criteria:
    Evaluate the rule when a record is created
```

Then, specify five field updates, one per field, to copy them from the account via a formula.

Do not enter the literal value "null" in the criteria. Just leave it blank.